# Running time of quicksort when attempting to sort an array of duplicate values

Tags: sorting, big-o

I am considering the case where quicksort is run on an array of all the same values, e.g:

`[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.......1]`

Is it correct that the running time in this scenario would be O(n^2)?

Comment: Yep.  I wonder why? 
You get the same behaviour when it is sorted.  You also get the same behaviour when it is sorted in reverse.

Comment: Erm. You get the same behaviour *because* it's sorted. Also, in reverse :)

Comment: @sehe Indeed, the array {1, 1, 1} is sorted. That is probably not apparent to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. For already ordered arrays and reverse ordered arrays the median of three rule avoids the quadratic runtime. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_element for improving the runtime on arrays where all entries are the same.

Comment: It might be notewothy that it is easy to construct an input to a Median-Of-Three quicksort that degrades to O(N^2)

Answer (score 1):

There is no one correct answer for all implementations of QuickSort.

Specifically, it depends on how you choose your pivot.

If you choose the first element as the pivot, yes, this would give O(N<sup>2</sup>).

If you choose the middle element or a typical median of 3 as the pivot, it'll be O(N log N).

Comment: The Hoare quicksort states a specific pivot. This makes that quicksort easy to analyse. Median of 3 is not a magic bullet.

Comment: Even the median of three rule wont yield O(N log N) runtime in this case. It just fixes the problem with preordered lists (forward or reverse).

Comment: It isn't a magic bullet, but as long as you're careful otherwise, it most certainly can work in this case (though yes, there equally certainly are other cases for which it will fail--in fact, for any deterministic selection of pivot, there will always be a bad case).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Hoare's paper did give one method of selecting a pivot, but made it quite clear that it was only one possible example, not a required part of the algorithm. "An awkward situation is liable to arise... This *may* be prevented by the use of **a** method..."

Comment: The median of [1,1,1] will be 1, so pivot=1 and the quicksort will recurse n times into the left branch, so u end up with O(N^2) again. The question was about that specific usecase and not a general discussion of the algorithms properties.

Comment: @KevinDreßler: A median of three will choose the middle of the three items, which will be the middle of the array. It will (if properly written) only exchange items if one in the upper half is strictly less than the pivot (none are) and one in the lower half strictly greater (again, none are), so it does no exchanges in this case. The array will thus be divided in the middle. It then selects a "new" partition as the median of three of the lower bound, which will (again) be the middle element. This results in only Log(N) partitioning steps, each taking O(N). Overall complexity is O(N log N).